# Can we compare a standardized version of a variable with a standard normal distribution to check a variable's normality?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, normality-assumption, standardization, qq-plot

I am currently exploring **ways to check the normality** of a given variable in the dataset. Since most algorithms assume a variable's gaussian distribution, it is important to check it.

#### A Q-Q Plot

Came across the *QQ plot* before, and have found that comparing the data points on the plot with the OLS line sounds helpful.

#### Now what if...

... we could **simply compare the distribution** with the standard normal distribution? Suppose, We have `kilometers` variable and to check its normality, I standardized it with $z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$

Then if I plot (KDE plot) like this:

[image]

As you can see, I have compared `kilometers` with the example normal distribution.  For the same distribution, the QQ plot is like this:

[image]

#### The question

> ***"Can we use the normal-comparison plot (the first plot) to check the normality or a QQ plot is the better solution?"***

The thing is, the QQ plot might take more time to compute the OLS trendline if the data size is bigger, while the comparison plot is, you know just a plot of the data after transformation and that might be quicker comparatively.

Please let me know, whether the comparison plot can serve the purpose or not.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that **QQ plot** is a _general_ name for **any plot of quantiles versus quantiles**. Those other quantiles could be quantiles from other data or theoretical quantiles from any distribution  thought relevant or helpful as a reference. Uniform quantiles can be used even when there is no indication that the distribution is or is close to a uniform distribution. The plot with uniform quantiles (often simply called a quantile plot) is in essence a plot of the empirical cumulative distribution function (ECDF) with axes reversed from the convention of cumulative probability on the $y$ axis.

Comment: So, the name QQ plot, although not wrong, is more general than what you're discussing here.

Comment: Depending slightly on your software, it is, or should be, easy to plot observed data against quantiles with the "same" mean and SD. Here "same" could be robust or resistant estimates using the sample data, or the usual estimates. That could be useful in showing (e.g.) that a fitted normal has **much** of its probability in impossible regions. (Any fitted normal will always have **some** probability in impossible regions.)

Answer (score 1):

The mean and SD are completely irrelevant in principle to whether a distribution is normal or Gaussian and so a standardized version of a variable provides just as much information for assessing that as the original data. An analogy could be that assessing whether a shape is circular in no sense depends on knowing the position of the shape centre or the shape size, however defined or measured.

There is just one reservation: the actual units are substantively informative. Thus for example a variable that is measured in km is one I would expect to be positive (or just possibly zero) and so being able to judge whether that variable was obviously constrained by zero (an common contributor to non-normality) is often helpful.

A kernel density plot is certainly a lot better than nothing for thinking about distribution shape but it requires a very good eye to distinguish on such a plot (for example) a normal distribution and a $t$ distribution with a few degrees of freedom.

A normal quantile plot (normal probability plot, normal scores plot, probit plot) is in contrast dedicated to the task of assessing closeness to normality. I don't regard a trend line as an especially helpful or essential adjunct, but -- notable detail -- those who do like these trend lines would often strongly prefer a robust line based on median and quartiles, and not a regression trend line. If you use a trend line it would be a good idea to find out how it was produced and to explain that to your readers.

I don't regard speed of computation as an issue either way.

Your example distribution is clearly not normal. What to do about that, possibly nothing, depends on what else you want to do.

Comparison plot is not especially transparent as a name. Many people have pointed out that all graphs are comparisons, one way or another.

All that said,

> most algorithms assume a variable's gaussian distribution

is one of the most common myths in statistical science!

Comment: I wanted to make sure that the "comparison plot" (left) is not misleading. Indeed it requires *"a good eye"* but still, if it serves the purpose to check the normality (to some degree) it would be my doubt clearer. Your detailed response clears many doubts. And if I haven't miss-understood you, then I can go with the comparison plot.

Comment: Not quite, as the normal quantile plot is always focused on the question. The only reservation is that some people need more practice with normal qiantile plots before they are comfortable with them, but that's true with any unfamiliar plot. Sometimes both plots are helpful.

Comment: I appreciate your knowledge and the details that you've put in. Thanks, it solves my problem.